# Java Jaxb unmarshall and endianness of data

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I am planning to use jaxb to unmarshall xml in to POJO. Now this pojo will be serialized and sent over network to some other application. Now some of this POJO contains a int field (4 or 8 bytes) which when read from xml need to be serialized in either little endian or big endian notation based on some flag. (this flag is not field by field but rather at application instance level). Is there anyway In Jaxb while unmarshalling can honor this endianness setting by some sort of annotation in xml?

Any help in this regards is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify your own `XmlAdapter` in your POJO:

```
@XmlElement(name="intField")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(EndianIntAdapter.class)
public int intField;
```

And then implement the adapter:

```
class EndianIntAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Integer> {
  @Override
  public String marshal(Integer field) throws Exception {
    //int to string based on endianness
  }

  @Override
  public Integer unmarshal(String str) throws Exception {
    //String from xml to int based on endianness
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,

Sorry for adding one more question, how to specify this custom XmlAdapter if this POJO Is generated by jaxb  xsd to pojo converter?